# LIT : Unable to import png | jpeg | svg files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, lit

In our project we are using LIT and as part of the architecture, we don't have any HTML pages. We create "template.ts" and **return html`<img src="../../assets/sample.png" />`** directly this way.

I have tried using, webpack "html-loader" & "file-loader" but it doesn't work. Is there any other way we can import png|svg|jpeg files?

**Note:** we are using webpack5, LIT and there are no .html except index.html(entry point).